# How can I set gradient colors on AppBar with conditions?

Tags: flutter, gradient

I want to set gradient colors on `AppBar` according to the user's level. What's wrong in this code?

```
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: levelState == Level.bronze ? [
                  Colors.red,
                  Colors.orange,
                ] : levelState == Level.silver ? [
                Colors.cyan,
                  Colors.amber,
                  ] : [
                  Colors.green,
                  Colors.blue,
                ],
                begin:  FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
                end:  FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
                stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
              )
          ),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: ()
          {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        title: Obx(() {
          final user = controller.user.value;
          return Text('$user?.user_name');
        }),
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
      ),
      body: Text('Level: ')
    );
  }
}
```

I want to set gradient colors on `AppBar` according to the user's level.

Comment: Have you used Getx Package?

Comment: Yes, I have. But I have not fully understood the package yet.

Comment: Share GetxController  code?